# Add another registration form in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, registration

I have a registration form on /register and I am trying to add another one for wholesale customers (ie. /register-wholesaler) which should be pretty much the same as the other one just a couple more fields (Business name etc.).

I suppose I need to start with register.phtml...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with defualt registration form,once you have created that page succesfully, later you  just need to add some new fields that you want to add for wholesale customer...